# ModernCV Chinese template empty after compiling

Tags: xetex, moderncv, cjk

I'm trying to compile the Chinese example template of the moderncv package: https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/5b173abf55d30fa6a79fd77dfe2065f287451835/examples/template-zh.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}   % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv 主题
\moderncvstyle{casual}                        % 选项参数是 ‘casual’, ‘classic’, ‘oldstyle’ 和 ’banking’
\moderncvcolor{blue}                          % 选项参数是 ‘blue’ (默认)、‘orange’、‘green’、‘red’、‘purple’ 和 ‘grey’
%\nopagenumbers{}                             % 消除注释以取消自动页码生成功能

% 字符编码
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % 替换你正在使用的编码
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

% 调整页边距
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}           % 如果你希望改变日期栏的宽度

% 个人信息
\name{小龙}{李}
\title{简历题目 (可选项)}                     % 可选项、如不需要可删除本行
\address{街道及门牌号}{邮编及城市}            % 可选项、如不需要可删除本行
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}              % 可选项、如不需要可删除本行
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}               % 可选项、如不需要可删除本行
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}                 % 可选项、如不需要可删除本行
\email{xiaolong@li.com.cn}                    % 可选项、如不需要可删除本行
\homepage{www.xialongli.com}                  % 可选项、如不需要可删除本行
\extrainfo{附加信息 (可选项)}                 % 可选项、如不需要可删除本行
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                  % ‘64pt’是图片必须压缩至的高度、‘0.4pt‘是图片边框的宽度 (如不需要可调节至0pt)、’picture‘ 是图片文件的名字;可选项、如不需要可删除本行
\quote{引言(可选项)}                          % 可选项、如不需要可删除本行

% 显示索引号;仅用于在简历中使用了引言
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother

% 分类索引
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            内容
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}                       % 详情参阅CJK文件包
\maketitle

\section{教育背景}
\cventry{年 -- 年}{学位}{院校}{城市}{\textit{成绩}}{说明}  % 第3到第6编码可留白
\cventry{年 -- 年}{学位}{院校}{城市}{\textit{成绩}}{说明}

\section{毕业论文}
\cvitem{题目}{\emph{题目}}
\cvitem{导师}{导师}
\cvitem{说明}{\small 论文简介}

\section{工作背景}
\subsection{专业}
\cventry{年 -- 年}{职位}{公司}{城市}{}{不超过1--2行的概况说明\newline{}%
工作内容:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item 工作内容 1;
\item 工作内容 2、 含二级内容:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item 二级内容 (a);
  \item 二级内容 (b)、含三级内容 (不建议使用);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 三级内容 i;
    \item 三级内容 ii;
    \item 三级内容 iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item 二级内容 (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item 工作内容 3。
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{年 -- 年}{职位}{公司}{城市}{}{说明行1\newline{}说明行2}
\subsection{其他}
\cventry{年 -- 年}{职位}{公司}{城市}{}{说明}

\section{语言技能}
\cvitemwithcomment{语言 1}{水平}{评价}
\cvitemwithcomment{语言 2}{水平}{评价}
\cvitemwithcomment{语言 3}{水平}{评价}

\section{计算机技能}
\cvdoubleitem{类别 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{类别 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{类别 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{类别 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{类别 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{类别 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{个人兴趣}
\cvitem{爱好 1}{\small 说明}
\cvitem{爱好 2}{\small 说明}
\cvitem{爱好 3}{\small 说明}

\section{其他 1}
\cvlistitem{项目 1}
\cvlistitem{项目 2}
\cvlistitem{项目 3}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-}             % 改变列表符号

\section{其他 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{项目 1}{项目 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{项目 2}{项目 5\cite{book1}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{项目 3}{}

% 来自BibTeX文件但不使用multibib包的出版物
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}% BibTeX的数字标签
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                    % 'publications' 是BibTeX文件的文件名

% 来自BibTeX文件并使用multibib包的出版物
%\section{出版物}
%\nocitebook{book1,book2}
%\bibliographystylebook{plain}
%\bibliographybook{publications}               % 'publications' 是BibTeX文件的文件名
%\nocitemisc{misc1,misc2,misc3}
%\bibliographystylemisc{plain}
%\bibliographymisc{publications}               % 'publications' 是BibTeX文件的文件名

\clearpage\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

It compiles (I get an `Unfortunately, the package xetex-def could not be installed.` error though), but in the output all CJK characters are missing.

[image]

What's happening here? The Spanish example compiles without problems. I'm on Windows with TexStudio compiling with xelatex.

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917). Links to external files are discouraged because your question might become meaningless if/when the link disappears (next week, or next year, or... ).

Comment: @campa Changed link and added code.

Comment: @sollniss 你换PDFLATEX吧。。。没有问题的

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pdflatex`, I compiled without any problem apart from the missing picture.
[image]

Comment: With pdflatex I get the following error:
`Font C70/gbsn/m/n/38/30=gbsnu30 at 38.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.`

Comment: @sollniss Do you have the needed font/s available?

Comment: @zareami10 Are they not included with the cjk package?

Comment: @sollniss I'm not really sure TBH, but I also can compile your code. Maybe try installing `arphic` and `arphic-ttf`? It seems `gbs`-whatever is in their directory according to [this page](http://www.tug.org/texlive//Contents/live/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/arphic/gbsnu/).

Comment: @sollniss Try update your TeX distribution first, refresh all fonts

Comment: @zareami10, @casperyc I removed the font specification (`\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{}`) and now it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `ctex` pacakge like this:

```
\usepackage{ctex}
```

and compile using `xelatex`. the package `CJKutf8` is too old.